# Can I read TCP/IP requests and response made to biometric device?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, biometrics

I am trying to develop a PHP app which can communicate with a Biometric Device. I have the following device :

(http://secur-eye.com/products/biometric-products/ip-biometric/S-B250CB.html)

There is a software that comes with the device which interacts with the device using TCP/IP over LAN.

I want to connect the device directly to my app and in order to do so I need to understand what requests are made to the device. Since I do not have the source code for the software, only option left is to monitor the TCP/IP requests and responses. Please guide me.

Comment: Three options: you either use phps socket functions for direct communications, but that requires some knowledge about the exact protocol spoken. Or, often easier, you use that software by means of calls to phps process handling functions. If the software acts like a daemon, so is executed in a persistent session based manner, then you can use a mix between both approaches and communicate via sockets with that software.

Comment: You can try and monitor the requests with fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) if the software is able to communicate over a proxy. Otherwise you can try wireshark. But the disadvantage of wireshark is that it can't decrypt https for you.

Comment: software is windows based and also does not work as a daemon. I have already researched on php sockets but the problem is I don't know the predefined function present in the machine.

Comment: You might be able to reverse engineer the protocol. But that is quite a lot of hassle and might fail, also it typically is illegal (why ever). So most likely not a real option. It might be interesting to take a look, though.